# What is delegation in julia?

Tags: design-patterns, polymorphism, julia, composition

I see occational references to delegation,
or the delegation design pattern in Julia.

What is this?

E.g. I see it mentioned in

- [This file in DataStructures.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl/blob/b11a10fba4d8a8e0e7eba569bd36c816fa948450/src/delegate.jl)

Comment: Your two examples mean two different things.  In the first link, the word is being used in the same sense that a boss would *delegate* work to an underling.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the exact meaning in the docs is unclear. I have removed that reference. In general though the sense of _delgate work to an underling_ is what delegate means in julialang world, and the metaprogrammiing is just a way to achieve that. (Note this is a self answered question, in response to someone asking me to explain it to them.)

Answer (score 4):

This is a form of polymorphism via composition (rather than inheritance)

Say one has a wrapper type, wrapping some instance of a concrete subtype of `AbstractT`
where the wrapper itself is intended to be a subtype of `AbstractT`
(Not nesc always true, but in general).

To add all the methods one exacts such a subtype of `AbstractT` to have,
we want to **delegate** some or all of those methods to the wrapped object.
We do this via metaprogramming.
There are a few varients on how to do this.
But in general it is a hard pattern to abstract so people often write their own.

Say that that all `AbstractT` subtypes should implement 
 1arg `length`, `size` and `mean`

```
struct WrappedT{T<:AbstractT} <: AbstractT
    backing ::T
    ...
end

for fun in (:(Base.length), :(Base.size), :(Statistics.mean))
    @eval ($fun)(x::WrappedT, args...) = ($fun(x.backing, args...))
end
```

Generally you won't delegate all the methods, since some you will want to do differently, that is the point of creating the new type after all.