# Creating custom types in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, how do I create custom types `MyOrderedDictA` and `MyOrderedDictB` such that:

1. Each has all the functionality of an `OrderdDict`, and can be passed to any function that accepts `AbstractDict`s
2. They are distinct from each other, so that I can take advantage of multiple dispatch.

I suspect\hope this is straightforward, but haven’t been able to figure it out.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789937/what-is-delegation-in-julia and note that if you want to create a _new_ type that behaves exactly as an OrderedDict just for dispatch purposes you might be doing something suboptimal.

Comment: Additionally this thread might help you: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/developing-pass-through-types/10717/10

Comment: The OP on the [Developing Pass-Through Types](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/developing-pass-through-types/10717) thread on Julia Discourse was wanting to do exactly what I want to do, though I think he posed the problem better than I did. But my expectation that creating a pass-through type would be easy seems to be wrong. I will experiment with the approach suggested by @crstnbr, but otherwise you might be correct to suggest that I'm doing something sub-optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you have to do is to define your type `MyOrderedDictA`, wrapping a regular `OrderedDict`, and forward all functions that one can apply to an `OrderedDict` to this wrapped dict.

Unfortunately, the `AbstractDict` [interface](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/interfaces/) is (to my knowledge) currently not documented (cf. `AbstractArray`). You could look at their definition and check which functions are defined for them. Alternatively, there is the more practical approach to just use your `MyOrderedDictA` and whenever you get an error message, because a function is not defined, you forward this function "on-the-fly".

In any case, using the macro `@forward` from [Lazy.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/Lazy.jl/blob/master/src/macros.jl#L264) you can do something along the lines of the following.

```
using Lazy

struct MyOrderedDictA{T,S} <: AbstractDict{T,S}
    dict::OrderedDict{T,S}
end

MyOrderedDictA{T,S}(args...; kwargs...) where {T,S} = new{T,S}(OrderedDict{T,S}(args...; kwargs...))

function MyOrderedDictA(args...; kwargs...)
    d = OrderedDict(args...; kwargs...)
    MyOrderedDictA{keytype(d),valtype(d)}(d)
end

@forward MyOrderedDictA.dict (Base.length, Base.iterate, Base.getindex, Base.setindex!)

d = MyOrderedDictA(2=>1, 1=>2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Others will be better placed to answer this, but a quick take:

1. For this you will need to look at the `OrderedDict` implementation, and specifically which methods are defined for `OrderedDict`s. If you want to be able to pass it to methods accepting `AbstractDict`s you need to subtype it like `struct MyDictA{T, S} <: AbstractDict{T, S}`
2. If you define two structs they will automatically be discting from each other!? (I might be misunderstanding the question here)